# C# Throw exception in server call back method

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I have a method in my program which is a server call back look like this:

```
        private void DeserializerCallback(IAsyncResult aysncResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)aysncResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response;
        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(aysncResult);
        }
        catch(WebException e)
        {
            VenueMapException venueMapException = new MyException(MyException.ExceptionType.BadResponseException, e);
            throw venueMapException;
        }

        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        this.DeserializeStream(responseStream);

    }
```

This method is called after I do this line:

```
this.MyHttpRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(this.DeserializerCallback), this.MyHttpRequest);
```

In the call back method, I throw a exception that defined by myself. Now I want to catch this exception as far from this code as possible, but I am not sure where will the exception go if I do not catch it in this method. 
Can someone give some suggestion? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors can be caught at Page Level or Application level

1. Errors can be caught at Application level in the Application_Error
   event in Global.asax
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx
2. Errors can be caught at Page Level by the Page_Error event in aspx pages
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx

And inside these events we can get the last occured exception by the code

```
Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();
```